# Old nuclear war film

Tags: story-identification, movie

This Film was during the gung-ho period of war movies 50-60's and I think black and white.

**What I remember**

Part of it was on an SAC airbase in the Midwest. They knew that there was going to be an attack so they converted some old powder bunkers to emergency shelters for all of the staff. When the attack occurred they were mostly spared. They were limiting exposure to the outside, but there was a fuel tank fire and many guys (remember the gung ho part) volunteered to stay out long enough to fight the fire

I think it was early color or black-and-white, but not sure.

It is not one of the more well known like *Looking Glass* or *A Day Called X* or *Power of decision*. It was in a documentary style if I remember like *Power of Decision*. It also is likely *not* an episode of a series like Motorola theater or anything. This was filmed with some decent backing.

That is all that I remember. I've only watched it, but have had a hankering for some of the older documentary style nuclear war films and this one is eluding me.

Comment: It's not the film you are seeking, but have you watched the BBC film "the War Game?" I was shown it at school in the 1960s and it was horrifying. At the time, the BBC, even though they had made it, banned it from broadcast.

Comment: That doesn't seem really sci-fi or fantasy. Sure, there's a war and people in a bunker but... That's all?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't really contain any Sci-Fi or Fantasy elements. Therefore, it is off-topic here...

Comment: It is classified as science fiction in Wikipedia. It does not necessarily mean it is Sci-Fi, but I just wanted to weigh in.

Comment: @C.Koca - what is classified as science fiction? Do you mean you found an answer as to what this is? If so, and it is indeed sci-fi then you can comment with it to get it unlocked and answer

Comment: @NKCampbell I checked the suggestion given in the first comment. Wiki suggests many genres, including Sci-fi.

Comment: I see - I think Jenayah was commenting that the film as described in the question doesn't seem like sci-fi, not addressing the suggesting in the comment @C.Koca

Comment: @Jenayah If OP edited the question to explicitly say that some nuclear weapons actually exploded, and that there were some actual post-apocalyptic could nditons, would you then consider it science fiction?

Comment: @Spencer - Then, I would vote to reopen, and I think that Jenayah would, as well... But it is written that this is a documentary-style film, so it seems to be nonfictional.

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath: There are many fictional films made like a documentary.

Comment: @Spencer possibly. But as this question is years old, wasn't edited until yesterday, and OP seems to be gone, I think this is abandoned and will likely stay closed forever.